# Cannot add Sass to Vue project in Webpack 3

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I just installed **sass-loader** and **node-sass** to my project via npm:

```
npm install -D node-sass sass-loader
```

Then replaced the style tag inside vue component to:

```html
<style lang="scss"></style>
```

I get the following error:

```
 Module build failed: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:39:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:432:7)
    at getSassOptions (C:\Users\tomek\Desktop\projekty\projectsBacketlist\noteTakingApp\frontend\noteTakkingApp\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\utils.js:160:37)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\tomek\Desktop\projekty\projectsBacketlist\noteTakingApp\frontend\noteTakkingApp\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:49) 
 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue 4:14-357 13:3-17:5 14:22-365
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Yes sure https://github.com/TomekPulkiewicz/NoteTakingAppFrontend'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of Webpack in your project (3.x) is old and incompatible with the newest versions of `node-sass` and `sass-loader` (5.x and 10.x, respectively).

For Sass in Webpack 3, install `node-sass` 4.x and `sass-loader` 7.x:

```
npm i -D node-sass@^4 sass-loader@^7
```

Comment: @nanobot Vue CLI scaffolds a Vue project for you. That is, the CLI's `create` command (`vue create myproject`) generates a project that automatically uses the correct version of Webpack, so you don't need to install Webpack explicitly. You may encounter tutorials that suggest `vue init webpack` to create a Webpack-enabled Vue project, but that [template has long since been **deprecated**](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack).

Comment: Ah that makes sense now. This is exactly what I was told in the tutorial from 2018.